# How do I load javascript from external source in a Sproutcore application?

Tags: sproutcore-2, typekit

I want to use typekit in a sproutcore app, which means I should add following javascript to my mainpage  tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://use.typekit.com/jfg6pfv.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">try{Typekit.load();}catch(e){}</script>
```

How do I do this in sproutcore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a file named "resources/page_javascript.rhtml":

```
<% content_for("page_javascript") do %>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://use.typekit.com/jfg6pfv.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">try{Typekit.load();}catch(e){}</script>
<% end %>
```